# Having an issue getting background images to behave the same on my webpage

Tags: html, css, image

http://codercarter.com

I am working on this site for a class, and I have an issue I cannot seem to find the problem for.  The background image at the EXPERIENCE section doesn't reach the ends of the pages like the first two background images do, and Im not sure what is causing it.  In addition to this on the old version of the site, the three contact buttons used to be side-by-side of each other, now when I see the new version there are two, and the github connection is below them and very wide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last image does not reach the edge because it is inside of the "portfolio" div, which has margins. For the button issue, you can assign something like "max-width: 30%;" to each of the 3 ".card" elements.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not seeing what you are referring to, looking at the code it looks to me like the three images are together at the top of the code?  
https://github.com/CoderCarter/CoderCarter.github.io/blob/master/index.html

Comment: It seems like the background image issue is fixed now because it has been moved outside of the parent div like I mentioned.

Comment: I see it now, that fixed it, ty so much!